# XSS prevention in PHP

Tags: php, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best practices for avoid xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoid-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

I need to prevent XSS attacks in PHP code, is there nay good and easy library for this?

Answer (score 11):

Security is not a product. It's a process.

If you rely on a library for security you're doomed to being attacked one time or another.

Anyway, you could sanitize your inputs with standard php functions (i.e. `htmlspecialchars()`)

Comment: ok  I added this to input that will be printed on page, will this prevent all XSS attacks or at least most of them ?

Comment: I suggest you read up on XSS. You need to understand how it works to protect against it.

Comment: @newbie no, you don't. or you wouldn't ask will this prevent all XSS attacks

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of PHP functions that can assist you in preventing XSS attacks. Take a look at these:

`strip_tags`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

`htmlspecialchars`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: htmlentities is better to be removed from the list. as this function is obsolete and dirty

Comment: Such a torrent of dirty functionality that it is hard to keep up with what is actually usable in PHP.

Comment: Um, what?  htmlentities is alive and well, and usually preferrable to htmlspecialchars http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 1):

Theres alot of good answers on google, first one I found; http://codeassembly.com/How-to-sanitize-your-php-input/

My main advice would be to consider every input as a direct attack.

So convert to html characters. Add slashes.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API

Comment: PHP: The current release of this project is not suitable for production use.

Answer (score -2):

`htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: I noticed that too, it prevented alert('XSS attack test!'); from running, so it must be doing something

Comment: That will make unicode characters unreadable (п => &#1087;)