# CKEditor security best practices

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, xss

I am using http://ckeditor.com/ in a small PHP/MySQL forum I built. My questions:

1. Is it safe to save user-created HTML like this in the database and then re-display it in my application? What precautions should I take to keep the users of my forum safe from script injection and the like?

   ```
   <p>test</p>
   <span style="font-size: 14px;">test</span>
   ```
2. Would it be safer to use BBCode instead of HTML? I tried the ckeditor bbcode plugin but it lacks some basic formatting like text alignment ... Does anyone know how to extend the plugin to add text alignment to it?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: Assuming the ckeditor is script-safe, your question is already adequately covered by the ckeditor documentation. Next time, please put more effort into writing your question.

Comment: am not saying ckeditor isn't safe am saying is't good or bad to save plain html in the database?

Comment: thanks for the answer and i don't have problem with my shift key and am not posting from a cell phone but why you are asking that?

Comment: Even if CKEditor was safe, it will not be an option to save plain HTMLin the database : you can never trust data from client. The server must always validate it. It is so easy to bypass client validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, there are two main things you need to do:

1. Safely save the user content to your database so that you are not vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. See this SO question for how best to handle that => [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).
2. Prevent someone from submitting unsafe HTML to your database that would then be re-displayed to your users and make them vulnerable to an XSS attack. There are plenty of questions that deal with that here on SO. Here's one => [XSS Prevention in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652138/xss-prevention-in-php).

Comment: but do you think that saving html not bbcode in the database good or bad?

Comment: I think HTML is okay if you have a good way for sanitizing it. BBCode is probably a little safer ... but I don't how to make the CKEditor BBCode plugin align the text as you want.

Comment: thanks man finally someone who understand what am asking. but isn't bad when i want to send search querys to the table that i save plain html in it.