# Secure entry but display correctly ckeditor

Tags: php, security, ckeditor

I'd like to use Ckeditor for an internal messaging system on a website.

I'd like that users can format text but I'm aware of vulnerabilities, is there any way to make a compromise ?

I've heard of a BBcode plugin, or ways to sanitize data entered from another topic ([CKEditor security best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225210/ckeditor-security-best-practices)), how would it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clean your code just in CKEditor (in client side ) check

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

PS. but i suggest to perform clean in backend too.