# Remote uploading images - file_get_contents(); to help me?

Tags: php

I'm wanting to create a website that allows an user to put a link in a field and once the user submits the form, the "image" link added to the field will be remote uploaded to my server (to the path I specified in my server).

A friend of mine did this once, and he told me that he used the file_get_contents() function to get this working, but I cannot figure out how I'd do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711597/is-it-safe-to-let-the-users-provide-the-link-for-their-image/3711697#3711697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_get_contents()  will read file contents into a variable.
if you need to **copy** file to your server, use `copy()` instead.

```
copy($_POST['link'],basename($_POST['link']));
```

Comment: you should note that the location of the link should be url encoded as `%20` / spaces causes issues in PHP 5.2.1 or prior.

Comment: How about remote uplaoding (copying) multiple files from links? Like getting all links from a textarea, and each of them should be separately uploaded to my server?

Comment: @Dugi what's so special with it? get your links into array and loop over them