# Adding a comment system to my website

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, comments

Hey everyone, I'm trying to add some type of comment system to my website for the news that I post on the main page. What I would like it to do is have anybody comment on it (they don't need to login). The comment submission form just required a Name and comment.
What would be the simplest way to do this? It would also be nice to have it display how many comments there currently are on the news post. I dont need anything fancy.
Thanks!

Comment: No login required = tons of comment spam. Whatever solution you go with, I suggest you incorporate captchas or something similar into it.

Comment: @eykanal I have such a site with comments. no logins at all and no spam as well. As a matter of fact, login itself doesn't provide any spam defense. If you have trouble with spamming other site, yoo can ask a question on stackoverflow and be stuffed with solutions in seconds

Comment: so, just sit down and write it, in the fashion you like. Not a big deal

Comment: Most spammers rely on scripts for common comment systems. If you're writing your own, it'll be a while before they find you. However, they did find me eventually. When I discovered this, I modified my system slightly, changing the name/method of the comment submission, while leaving the old system intact but doing nothing. Spammers continued to hit the old system for a while and then stopped. This was years ago. I think today I'd use Akismet or implement some moderation/login system if I had a problem, but I wouldn't worry about it from the get go.

Comment: The spam will find your site eventually, and when they do it'll be a blood bath.

Comment: We like to use akismet, with a captcha fallback when akismet fails (I hate captchas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple [php guest book tutorial](http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/15.html). I know its not exactly what you asked for, but its very similar.  Customize it to suit your need.  PS:  i would really think about what eykanal wrote.  *You would need to add a column for the article id, page id etc...*

#### Follow-up:

As everyone has mentioned, this example/tutorial is not the most secure/correctly designed piece of work and is only meant to show you the level of complexity and give you and idea of what you're getting into.  After reading it i would also read a bit on php/mysql injection vulnerabilities and simple db design principals

Comment: Who is that mentally disabled dude who wrote this "tutorial"?

Comment: Thank you, im surprised by how quickly people respond to you on this site. I will definitely try this method out!

Comment: @MJ93: Do be careful of SQL injection attacks in your implementation.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I know right, its got lots of flaws and breaks most db design rules, but having been in MJ93's position at some point, it helped me get started.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to code your own comment system, you can use http://disqus.com/

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do that... i try to give you a simple idea (without use patterns or complex method):

**1)** Create a Database Table to contain comments, i suggest these fields:

```
id (integer)
news_id (fk to id of the news) 
date (i.e. Timestamp)
name (varchar(30... or less))
message (text)
```

**2)** In your frontEnd page add a form composed of 4 fields: 
news-id : self-explanatory
name : input text field 
message : textarea 
captcha: (to avoid bot completion) i suggest you [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

```
<form action="add_comment.php" method="POST">
  <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

  <label for="name">Your Comment:</label>
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>

  <input type="hidden" name="news_id" value="<?php echo $news_id?>"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Ok" name="save"/>
</form>
```

This form send data in POST to add_comment.php that need to implement these steps:

**2.A)** check if $_POST data exist

```
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
```

It would be better check provenience of data (to be sure that are from your site).

**2.B)** If $_POST data exists,check mandatory fields and store error in some structure:

```
if( (trim($_POST["name"]) == "") and (strlen($_POST["name"]) < 5) ){
  $name_error = true;
}
```

**2.C)** If there aren't errors, save data to the database:
- open db connection 
- assemble a query. Do not forget to wrap every variable into quotes and run it through mysql_real_escape_string (or use prepared statements)
- run this query
- redirect to the current page

**2.D)** If there are errors, redirect to main page with a variable in get &error=1. 
In your main page check if this variable is set to define if you need to print some error messages.
(better to stay on the same page and display errors as well as fill entered data ([avoid xss scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoid-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site) ))

**3)** Manage your main page adding a script to select comment from DB, here some steps:

**3.A)** For each news you print, get the id (or the unique key used to store news in db).

**3.B)** Perform a simple select query like this to get all comment for this news:

```
$query = "SELECT name,message from comments where id_news = '{$_newsid}' order by date DESC";
```

**3C)** For each comment you obtain with this query you can print data in this way :

```
<?php foreach($query_fetched_results as $comment):?>
<p class='name'><?php echo $comment['name'];?></p>
<p class='comment_body'><?php echo $comment['message'];?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

**4)** Check number of comment is pretty simple, perform a count on data obtained from query at point 3B.

Comment: Thank you col shrapnel! the hidden field in the form in point 2 is indispensable! Thank you also for the any other info added!

Answer (score 2):

Aside from handling spam, this is fairly simple.  It's a great learning exercise the first time through.

To save the comments...

In your HTML, you make a form with your comment fields.  Submit the form with POST.

In your PHP, read the fields out of $_POST and check them for validity - name is x characters long, not blank, etc.  Run your data from the user through [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and put it together in an INSERT query string.  Run the query.  A key idea here - don't trust the users input - check it every way you can think of.  There's loads of help on Stack Overflow on the subject.

To display the comments...

Run a SELECT query looking for the ID that corresponds to your posting.  Output names and comments to a string (using strip_tags() to remove unwanted HTML from comments), introducing your own layout HTML as needed.  You can easily count the comments as you output each comment to your string.  Then output the formatted comments to the page.

There are lots of options to consider along the way - do you want to allow certain HTML?  How are you handling the inevitable spam?  Are you threading comments, allowing avatars, Gravitars, email addresses, URLS for posters, etc?  Are you making the posts through some system or just building pages?

EDIT:  corrected my suggestion on mysql_real_escape_string().  Thanks to Col. Shrapnel for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: run whole query through mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: Oh, that was dumb.  I'll fix that.

Comment: In fact, mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with user input. it's database stuff. It should be done even there was no user input at all. it's just like formatting of some sort, a syntax rule. SQL syntax. And mysql_real_escape_string would help you nothing. **It works only within quotes.**

Answer (score 1):

you can use [IntenseDebate](http://intensedebate.com).

> ***features:***
>
> **Comment Threading**
>
> Improve the conversation within the
>   comment section and reply directly to
>   an individual comment. Indented
>   replies make following various
>   conversations manageable.
>
> **Reply-By-Email**
>
> Respond to and moderate comments with
>   ease via email, even if you're on the
>   go. Just because you're away from your
>   computer doesn't mean the conversation
>   stops.
>
> **Email Notifications**
>
> Commenters receive email alerts when a
>   response to their comment is posted,
>   linking them directly to the response.
>   Add in reply-by-email, along with the
>   option to subscribe to all comments
>   and let the debate ensue!
>
> ntenseDebate features
>
> **Email Notifications**
>
> Commenters receive email alerts when a
>   response to their comment is posted,
>   linking them directly to the response.
>   Add in reply-by-email, along with the
>   option to subscribe to all comments
>   and let the debate ensue!
>
> **Commenter Profiles**
>
> Commenter profiles let you and your
>   readers learn more about each other.
>   Watch the conversation go to new
>   levels once you and your readers are
>   able to get to know each other. Don't
>   forget, their universal profiles can
>   be used on any site with
>   IntenseDebate!
>
> **Moderation/Blacklisting**
>
> IntenseDebate offers some truly
>   hardcore moderation options. Customize
>   your settings to moderate by keywords,
>   number of links, commenter email,
>   and/or IP addresses.
>
> **Reputation Points & Comment Voting**
>
> Your readers will start to build their
>   commenter reputations when they create
>   an IntenseDebate account. Their
>   reputation score is based on the
>   quantity, and more importantly the
>   quality, of the comments they've made
>   across all sites with IntenseDebate.
>   Bring the quality comments to the
>   forefront.
>
> **Plugins API**
>
> We've opened up our code for
>   developers to introduce their own
>   creations into the debate. These
>   enhancements include Seesmic video
>   comments, PollDaddy polls, YouTube
>   videos, smileys, and more. Interested
>   in building your own customizations?
>   Check out our Plugins API.
>
> **OpenID**
>
> Your readers can post comments easily
>   using their OpenID. They can tie their
>   OpenID to their IntenseDebate profile
>   so they won't have to worry about
>   remembering another set of login
>   credentials.
>
> **Widgets**
>
> We've built some fancy widgets based
>   on your feedback. You can display your
>   blog's comment stats, the most recent
>   comments made on your blog, your most
>   popular posts, the most recent
>   comments you've made, and even who the
>   top IntenseDebaters are.
>
> **Twitter**
>
> Give your commenters the option to
>   send a simultaneous tweet when they
>   post a comment. It's a great way to
>   let your commenters spread the word
>   about your site and drive new traffic
>   and comments!
>
> **Facebook Connect**
>
> Open up the debate and let anyone with
>   a Facebook account post comments on
>   your site with our Facebook Connect
>   integration!
>
> **RSS Readers & Tracking**
>
> RSS readers make life simple. That's
>   why we've integrated IntenseDebate
>   comments with Google Reader and
>   Bloglines (with more RSS readers on
>   the way) so you can read and post
>   comments directly from your RSS
>   reader.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT RECOMMENDED Basic PHP form which store comments in a text file:**

a) Copy and Paste below code in your "php file" where you want to display comment form.

b) Make a file "comments.txt" in same folder where you have your "php file".

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

if ($_POST)
    {
    $handle = fopen("comments.txt", "a");
    fwrite($handle, $name . ":<br/>" . $comment . "<br/>");
    fclose($handle);
    }

?>

<form method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Comment:<textarea name="comment"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
</form>

<?php include "comments.txt"; ?>
```