# Removing Metacharacters in php

Tags: php, special-characters

We are using PHP code. For security reason we need to remove the Metacharacters from User Supplied Datas.

How is it possible by preg or any other inbuilt function is in PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by Metacharacters? Which characters, specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by metacharacters?

Comment: `preg_replace('/the Metacharacters/', '', $User_Supplied_Datas)` ?

Comment: @sberry2A: That is getting really old.

Comment: except () [] {} <> & $ characters, Any inbuilt php function is there?

Comment: except () [] {} <> & $ characters, Any inbuilt php function is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean "Characters which cause SQL Injection or XSS problems".

No, you don't. Just practise good escaping practises before you [make queries](http://bobby-tables.com/), or [output markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoid-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site).

Comment: yes, your answer is useful for my backend (database) preparation.