# How can I prevent an XSS attack that places a <script> element in the query string?

Tags: php, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best practices for avoid xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoid-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

For example:

```
http://www.mid-day.com/searchresult.php?query=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22This%20is%20vulnerable%20for%20XSS%20..%20by%20binny%22%29%3C/script%3E
```

This website has an XSS DOM based vulnerability I want to know what causes this vulnerability and how to prevent it?

Comment: more possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xss+php

Comment: On a sidenote, you might get answers for your specific site if you would put the relevant portions of code into the question (or on a codepad or pastebin) instead of expecting people to follow a shortlink that leads god knows where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always HTML encode values that come from the user like querystring parameters before outputting them. You could use the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

Instead of:

```
$str = $_GET['a'];
echo $str;
```

use:

```
$str = $_GET['a'];
echo htmlentities($str);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should never echo directly what is in a $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET, or $_SERVER variables.

If you have something like this:

`index.php?text=hai`

and you say:

`echo $_GET['text']`

It isn't safe.
If you put scripts in there or something:

`index.php?text=<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>`

It will display the document cookie. Not realy safe.

Same is with $_REQUEST and $_POST when you submit something. And with $_SERVER['THIS_URI']...

`index.php?url=<script><!-- something --></script>`

and you do

`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['THIS_URI']; ?>">` then you get an XSS hack too.

Allways use `htmlentities($string)` and in MySQL queries `mysql_real_escape_string($string)`.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/):

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   **malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS**) with a thoroughly audited,
>   secure yet permissive whitelist,   it
>   will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only
>   achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Built-in PHP functions do not respond to all sorts of attacks, a reason why such open source solution was needed.

I would also suggest you to take a look at:

- [PHP Security Guide](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)