# How do I remove HTML tags from a string?

Tags: php

I have a php script, where the user inserts his name.
Users can insert anything they want, even things like `<img src="...`.

I would like to save their input in a way it won't show any image (or any html).
I know it exists but I don't know what keywords to search in order to find what does it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

Comment: I edited your title for anyone searching for this in the future, but you may want to specify if you want to **remove** the tags entirely or simply **escape** them so they appear as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

Use `strip_tags($str)`.

http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is the PHP function [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), which does exactly what the name suggests, and strips HTML tags from a string.

The other alternative is to 'escape' the input, so that HTML characters such as `<` and `>` are converted into displayable text. This would result in the HTML code being displayed.

You would do this with the function [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

It's worth pointing out that the input may contain HTML characters without actually intending to be HTML. The `&` character is a HTML reserved character, but can also be found in normal text. `>` and `<` are less commonly used in normal text, but still possible. All of them may cause problems when displayed on your page, without necessarily being actual HTML code.

The solution to this is as above, to escape the string using `htmlentities()`. You may want to run `striptags()` first, but you should also run `htmlentities()` as well, to ensure that the string is displayed correctly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will encode the text so that the tags are not interpreted as HTML.