# insert multiple rows from array into table with unique ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multiple-insert

I have copied and modified a script off the internet. The script originally deleted selected records from a mysql table query. I have modified the script to insert the selected records into another table with the insert into statement.

I would like to know how I can insert all the selected records from the mysql array into the other table with the same id.

The logic is simlar to that of an 'orderdetails' table. I want all products ordered to have the same ordernumber so they share a common value.

How can I modify the below script to insert all values from the array with a unique number?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass")or die("cannot connect");    
mysql_select_db("db")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM category";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><form name="form1" method="post">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Insert multiple rows in mysql</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Category ID</strong></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Category</strong></td></tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox" name=check[]  value="
<?php echo $rows['cat_id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['cat_id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['category']; ?></td></tr>

<?php
}
?>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td></tr>
<?php
$check=$_POST['check'];
if($_REQUEST['delete']=='Delete'){
  {
    $sql="INSERT INTO category1 (cat_id,category) 
             SELECT cat_ID, category 
             FROM category 
             WHERE cat_id='$val'";

    foreach($check as $key=>$value)
    {
      $sql="INSERT INTO category1 (cat_id,category) 
              SELECT cat_ID, category 
              FROM category 
              WHERE cat_id='$value'";
      $final = mysql_query($sql);
      if($final) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=php.php\">";
      }
    } 
  }
}
// Check if delete button active, start this   
// if successful redirect to php.php

mysql_close();
?>
</table></form></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Have you considered doing it in one statement? `INSERT ... SELECT ...`?

Comment: Hi Mark, I would prefer to do it in one comment definately, the shorter the better but am an absolute novice to PHP so learning my way. I am using the insert ... select ... statement in MySQL which allows me to inser the selected rows from the array. How do I modify the statement to assign all inserted records the same unique ID.  I would like to use the select max(columnname) feature but am not sure how to nest this in the existing statement. any ideas?m Thanks again.

Comment: You would have to calculate the MAX in a subquery. `SELECT (SELECT MAX(...) FROM ... WHERE), other columns`. I'd post an answr but there's way too much code in your question, and not enough description of what you are trying to do, and I don't really want to read all that code.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has several issues:

A- You have SQL-injection holes:  Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`
B- You have possible XSS vulnerabilities: Use `htmlspecialchars` to escape all $vars that you echo.
C- Using `select *` when you're only going to use the fields `catID`, `category` is waste full. Always name the fields you select explicitly.

See:
[How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
[What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)
[What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)

**To answer your question**
I would use code something like

```
$check = $_POST['check'];
if (is_array($check)) {
  //simple test to see if an array is multi-dimensional.
  if (count($array) != count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) 
  {
     //die("multidimensional array's are not allowed");
     //insert code to reask the array, or work around the issue.
     //you really should not use `die` in production code.
  } else {
  //escape what's inside the array, not the array itself.
  $check = array_walk($check, 'mysql_real_escape_string');
  $check = "'".implode("','",$check)."'"; //1,2,3 => '1','2','3'
} else { //not an array
  $check = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($check)."'";
}
//Inserts all $check's in one go.
$sql = "INSERT INTO category1 (cat_id,category) 
          SELECT cat_ID, category 
          FROM category 
          WHERE cat_id IN ($check) ";  //$check is already quoted.
```

Comment: Hi @Johan, I tried inserting the code you mentioned above however I get the error message '•The website has a programming error.' when trying to openthe web page. I have replaced the last <?PHP ... ?> section with the code you provided. Do you have any ideas, is it possible to post the complete script that works? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @RyanSmith, it's not copy-pasteble code, you will need to do some rewriting yourself to actually make it work within your situation.