# Exploding php posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
id:10 Ivysaur Level:5
```

stored in side $_POST[A]

I'm trying just to grab the id (so the 10) and the name (which in this case is Ivysaur) and I want to store them in a session variable. But before I store them I'm trying to explode it so can split it into parts

```
$phoneChunks = explode("-", $_POST[A]);
echo "Raw Phone Number = $rawPhoneNumber <br />";
echo "First chunk = $phoneChunks[0]<br />";
echo "Second chunk = $phoneChunks[1]<br />";
echo "Third Chunk chunk = $phoneChunks[2]";
```

I am getting

```
Raw Phone Number =
First chunk = Id:10 Ivysaur Level:5
Second chunk =
Third Chunk chunk =
```

What am i doing wrong ???

Comment: In that data you provided, there is no hyphen, so `explode()` is just going to return the original string inside an array.

Comment: hyphen ??? how would i explode it then ? how can i add a "hyphen"  ?

Comment: "Hyphen" is the name for the `-` character, which you pass as first parameter to explode().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$chunk = explode(" ", $_POST['A']);
```

it should produce something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id:10
    [1] => Ivysaur
    [2] => Level:5
)
```

Comment: @Johan: I don't really like escaping data early on. I will always escape it RIGHT before sending it to database or processing it further that require escaping or XSRF.

Comment: In the OP's code, the very next statement is an echo, you don't have the option to escape it at a later time.

Comment: if you use OP's question, I agree that I SHOULD escape it. But, echo is not what OP want. He/she want to store it in SESSION.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match("/id:(\d+) (.+?) Level:(\d+)/",$_POST['A'],$match);
list(,$id,$name,$level) = $match; // don't forget extra , at beginning of list!
```

Now you have the variables `$id`, `$name` and `$level` to do whatever you want with. Good luck from there :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to explode on a dash when there is no dash in your string.   Try this:

```
$phoneChunks = explode(" ", $_POST[A]);
```

Answer (score -1):

> What am i doing wrong ???

You are not escaping `$_POST['A']`

```
$phoneChunks = explode(' ',hmtlentities($_POST['A']));
```

See: [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)