# php, how to use strip_tags or urldecode on REQUEST_URI?

Tags: php, urlencode, strip-tags

i have a link that needs ti be cleaned up a bit.

```
http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'" />
```

this link will generate something like this:

```
http://www.site.com/friends.php
```

where `friends.php` is the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

sometimes i pass an id to the link:

```
 http://www.site.com/friends.php?id=123456
```

what i want is to use strip_tags or urldecode to clean this link and make sure that whatever is passed in the `id` is an int and contains no letters, but i need to do it on the original link: `http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'" />`

edit:

i want the link to be cleaned out so i can't do this to it:

```
http://www.site.com/friends.php?id=<script>alert(TK00000006)</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

Comment: The example is certainly implicating they want to avoid XSS attacks, but the question has little to do with XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This assumes that you only have id in your query string:**

```
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
    . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
    .'?id='
    .filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Resulting id from `id=<script>alert(TK00000006)</script>` is `?id=00000006`.

---

**Alternate answer:**

```
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
    . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
    .'?id='
    .urlencode($_GET['id']);

//or effectively the same thing using only $_SERVER variables,
//but is much more robust as it handles multiple query parameters:
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
    . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
    .$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Resulting id from `id=<script>alert(TK00000006)</script>` is `?id=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28TK%29%3C%2Fscript%3E`

Comment: this is what i came up with finally: `http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?id='.urlencode(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_GET['id']))`

Comment: @Patrioticcow . . . What is the point of doing the the preg_replace and the urlencode?  My guess is that it gives you the same answer as I do, but that's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If ID cannot be zero, I'd do it like this:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
if ($id)
...      // valid number > 0
else
...      // invalid
```

Comment: As it can be a-z, I would assume it can be 0, too.

Comment: nope, you didn't understand my question. i want to do the cleanup on the link itself

Comment: otherwise i can do `$id= preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_REQUEST['id']);`