# return mysql result set in Foreach for my getAll function

Tags: php, mysql, function, foreach, resultset

might be a basic one but i wrote a function that selects all from a dbtable in backend. But in front end, i want to use it with foreach to display results wherever i want.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [stockCatID] => 1
        [stockCatName] => Copper
        [stockParentCat] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [stockCatID] => 2
        [stockCatName] => Zinc
        [stockParentCat] => 0
    )
)
```

When I send resultset to my front-end page, this array shows up. So I can't basically play it with:

```
<?php
$r = getAll("stockcategories");
foreach($r as $k=>$v) {
    echo ("<p><strong>$k</strong>: $v</p>");   
}
```

With above result array iu outputs:

```
0 = Array1 = Array
```

Added: I don't want to echo from backend function.

So finally it is my function:

```
<?php
function getAll ($tableName,$orderBy="", $limit="") {
        $orderBy = $orderBy == "" ? $orderBy : (" ORDER BY =\"".$orderBy."\" "); 
        $limit = $limit == "" ? $limit : (" LIMIT =\"".$limit."\" ");
        $q  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName $orderBy $limit");
        if (!$q) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());} else { $num=mysql_numrows($q); 
        if ($num != 0 ) { 
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { 
                $rArray[] = $r;
            }
            mysql_free_result($q); 
            return $rArray; 
            } else { echo '<span class="notification n-error">No Record Found</span>'; return false; }        
    }
?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is a very bad idea for a security point of view. And you're also not sanitizing your output, so if there's anything user supplied in there you're wide open to XSS.

Comment: Well to understand you better @Johan, while being inserted in mysql table, i **secure** inputs `function secure($string_to_clear)
    {
        $string_to_clear = @trim($string_to_clear);
        $string_to_clear = strip_tags($string_to_clear);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $string_to_clear = stripslashes($string_to_clear);
        }
        $string_to_clear = mysql_real_escape_string($string_to_clear);
        return $string_to_clear;
    }` with this. Still open to XSS?

Comment: All that escaping works against one another defeating the purpose. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site

Comment: Thank you for reference link. I will deep into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rArray` is a 2 dimensional array but you are accessing it in only one dimension.  You need nested `foreach` loops.  The outer loop iterates over each row returned, and the inner iterates over the columns in each row:

```
foreach ($r as $row) {
  foreach($row as $k=>$v) {
    echo ("<p><strong>$k</strong>: " . htmlspecialchars($v) . "</p>");   
  }
}
```

**Update** a function to iterate over both dimensions:

```
function printResults($resultArray) {
    foreach ($resultArray as $row) {
      foreach($row as $k=>$v) {

        // Note sanitizing against XSS if this was user-input...
        echo ("<p><strong>$k</strong>: " . htmlspecialchars($v) . "</p>");   
      }
    } 

}
```

Call it as:

```
$r = getAll("stockcategories");
printResults($r);
```

Comment: thank you. It works in that way. But is there any way to leave only one for each in front end?

Comment: @yahyaE You will always need two loops to iterate over two dimensions.  You can wrap it in a function to do one function call in the front end. I'm adding that above..

Comment: Thank you for reply, will follow this way.

Answer (score 0):

As you yourself point out, the array contains arrays as values. `$v` is an array with the keys `stockCatID`, `stockCatName` and `stockParentCat`. Try something like:

```
$r = getAll("stockcategories");
foreach($r as $record) {
    foreach($record as $k=>$v) {
        echo("<p><strong>$k</strong>: $v</p>");
    }
    echo("<hr/>");
}
```

Comment: thank you. It works in that way. But is there any way to leave only one for each in front end?

Comment: @yahyaE, it depends on what you want to do. If you want to loop through all records, you need a `foreach`. Then if you want to loop through all the values of a record, you need a `foreach`. If you already know the names of the keys you're interested in, you can just `echo $v['stockCatID']` for example, instead of using a `foreach` to loop through all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$outer_array = getAll("stockcategories");
foreach($outer_array as $inner_array) {
    foreach($inner_array as $k => $v {
      echo "<p><strong>$k</strong>: $v</p>";
    }
}
```

you have an array of arrays, and your loop only traverses the outer array.

Comment: thank you. It works in that way. But is there any way to leave only one for each in front end?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it in one loop like this:

```
foreach($r as $row) {
    echo ("<p><strong>$row['stockCatName']</strong>: $row['whatever']</p>");   
}
```

Depends what output you need, really.