# PHP output to be shown for a second

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an url `http://www.example.com/?req=welcome`.

To get the parameter `req` I use PHP like this:

```
      echo $_GET['req'];
```

This will show the message in the body but this output should vanish after a second.

How do i do that?

Comment: in fact this question has nothing to do with php and echo.

Comment: That's a XSS security hole, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use javascript.

You can see an example of that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/ezgPT/), using jquery. It's possible to do it without that framework (or any framework). .delay would be replaced by setTimeout() which would enclose your fade out function.

Comment: :That req is in URL.How to get that through js.

Comment: :Is this statement necessary $('#wow').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);

Comment: @tereško Understood. I should have outlined the javascript method as well, or to start with.

Comment: `setInterval()`? Are you sure you didn't mean `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Wow, this is by fast my worst contribution to stack overflow. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id='req'><? echo $_GET['req']; ?></div>
```

Then use JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
      setTimeout(function (){
         document.getElementById('req').textContent = '';
      }, 1000); // 1000 is 1s. Set this to how many seconds you want to allow the request to be displayed for.
});
```

Comment: I posted my answer *only* because everyone else was suggesting jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - PHP is a server-side language, it has no control over the browser after it finishes sending the output.

Note that you *could* put your echoed code into a HTML element like a `div`, and hide it with JavaScript some time after the page loads. Example using jQuery for simplicity:

```
<div id="hidethisafterawhile"><?php  echo $_GET['req']; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       window.setTimeout(function(){
         $("#hidethisafterawhile").hide();
       },1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @tereško: Did you not understand "example" and "for simplicity"? jQuery is good for showing the relevant parts of the example, as you don't need to worry about `addEventListener` not working in IE6, or the various browser quirks in `textContent`. Nowhere did I say that it's the One True Way of using JS - just that making this example cross-browser without jQuery would detract from its intent.