# How can I prevent injection(html,php)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

I have a `<textarea>` and an `<input>` for comments of my site.Obviously, I `echo` them in an interface page and inserting into my database.

I want to know what do I have to do, when a person injects (for example) a `<img>` to damage the page or sending a query to damage database?

What is a simple way?

I've tried to search `< > ' " drop`  using but although I used `\"` instead of `"` but it doesn't work and in PHP, I've got error.

Is searching these characters manually the best way (PHP and Javascript)?

Comment: You are confusing manually with simple. Use escaping functions according to context. Strings that go in the database use the database escaping function. Strings that go back into pages use a HTML escaping function.

Comment: Two separate questions here. See [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) and [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to acheive is to prevent a form of [XSS (Cross site scripting attacks)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. You are trying to prevent the persistent variety:

> The persistent (or stored) XSS vulnerability is a more devastating
>   variant of a cross-site scripting flaw: it occurs when the data
>   provided by the attacker is saved by the server, and then permanently
>   displayed on "normal" pages returned to other users in the course of
>   regular browsing, without proper HTML escaping. A classic example of
>   this is with online message boards where users are allowed to post
>   HTML formatted messages for other users to read.

There are numerous options to prevent them. [OWASP has a neat explanation.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29). Go through it and find out. But mostly its a very big problem for an Individual to handle solely.

The best way is to use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which is both simple and easy. It may be a bit slow. But the extra processing is worth it. To give you an example of how simple it is to use here is a basic code:

```
<?php
    require_once '/path/to/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
?>
```

PS: HTMLPurifier has options to "whitelist". Use that for your advantage.

> For example, you can fine tune allowed elements and attributes,
>   convert relative URLs to absolute ones, and even autoparagraph input
>   text! These are, respectively, %HTML.Allowed, %URI.MakeAbsolute and
>   %URI.Base, and %AutoFormat.AutoParagraph. The %Namespace.Directive
>   naming convention translates to:
>
> ```
> $config->set('Namespace.Directive', $value);
> ```
>
> E.g.
>
> ```
> $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p,b,a[href],i');
> $config->set('URI.Base', 'http://www.example.com');
> $config->set('URI.MakeAbsolute', true);
> $config->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', true);
> ```

**EDIT:**

To answer your question on stopping malformed SQL Injection attacks refer to this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/728863)

Quote:

```
Use prepared statements and parameterized queries. These are SQL statements that sent to and parsed by the database server separately from any parameters.

If you use PDO you can work with prepared statements like this:

$preparedStatement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$preparedStatement->execute(array(':name' => $name));

$rows = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
where $db is a PDO object, see the PDO documentation. The mysqli class also provides parameterized queries.
```

Answer (score -1):

i never had problems using this:

```
$login = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|update|declare|exec|set|cast|$|#|%|&|'|\"|`|;|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['comment'])))));
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `addslashes($your_variable)` functon. this will add a back slashes before special character and use `stripslashes($db_result)` to wipe out the unwanted slashes.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

You can also use 
mysql_real_escape_string()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php