# change the div content based on the $_GET value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a main php file where i have a 'navbar' with links to various pages, on click of the 'navbar' item i want the content of the div replace with the respective page.

navbar.php:

```
<li id="nav-home"><a class="button" href="main.php">Home</a></li>
<li id="nav-attn"><a class="button" href="?nav=page1.php">Page1</a></li>    
<li id="nav-tran"><a class="button" href="?nav=page2.php">Page2</a></li>
<li id="nav-mr"><a class="button" href="?nav=page3.php">Page3</a></li>
```

main.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#content').load('<?php echo $_GET['nav'] ?>');           
});
</script>
```

With this code am expecting that on click of the navbar item the div content has to change to respective page reference.
what i found is, for example when i click on page1 my url is being changed to main?nav=page1.php, but the script to change the div content is not triggered at all.
Please correct me however i don't want to change the link to '#'.

Comment: You have a huge [XSS security hole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site) there, and it is rather pointless (and inefficient and search engine unfriendly) to follow a link to a new page only to use Ajax to load all the content. Just include the content with PHP.

Comment: I was gonna say the same thing, just either include the content straight away with AJAX or PHP, but don't use such an ineffective way like this one

Comment: what if i enter url `http://example.com/main.php?nav=main.php`?? :))

Comment: Just a suggestion : You can use twitter bootstrap for this..as it has inbuilt functionality for this kind of thing and it makes life easier..better you can try backbone.js ..:)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('uL#navbar a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('ul li a.button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for it

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.button').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    })
</script>

<li id="nav-home"><a class="button" href="main.php">Home</a></li>
<li id="nav-attn"><a class="button" href="?nav=page1.php">Page1</a></li>    
<li id="nav-tran"><a class="button" href="?nav=page2.php">Page2</a></li>
<li id="nav-mr"><a class="button" href="?nav=page3.php">Page3</a></li>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: 1) Is it the same? 2) Why did you add the same answer as sheikh? 3) Try to understand that usually it takes time to type and test and submit.

Comment: 1) yes, it's the same 2) skheik added answer after me 3) what tests :D no offence, but IMO there is no point to duplicate answers

Comment: here when i use the code my url is not changing and the div is replacing with the same page contents, but in the new div i have a form where the action should  keep me in the same page. Whats happening is when i submit the form with the new div am being redirected to main.php, which i don't want. how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));           
    });
});
```

in your php, change code so that the echo look like;

```
<li id="nav-attn"><a class="button" href="yourpage.php?nav=page1.php">Page1</a></li>
```