# PHP OWASP TOP 5 - Protection against Cross-site scripting (XSS) list item 4 and 5

Tags: php, xss, urlencode, html-entities, owasp

At https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5#How_to_Determine_if_you_are_Vulnerable_2 link, under title P2: Cross-site scripting > How to Protect Against It; in item 4 and 5 it's written that:

1. **item 4:** Free text input can only be safely re-displayed to the user
   after using HTML entities
2. **item 5:** Variables sent back to the user via URLs must be URL encoded
   using urlencode(), although the use of GET requests is deprecated
   for anything besides navigation purposes

### My Questions

#### Q1

For **item 4** it's explicitly said that *can only* but I remember I read that `htmlspecialchars()` is enough & more efficient vs `htmlentities()`. (An example source link about superiority of `htmlspecialchars`. Please read the comment of *Pornel_*: [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site?rq=1)) So I am confused after this input of OWASP. Should I replace my  `htmlspecialchars()` with `htmlentities()` that I use while I print the MySQL user inputted data to the screen as html.

#### Q2

For my forms (add article, add comment, e-mail to admin) I utilize `Post - Redirect - Session Variables` flow. (My explanation may be stupid for you but I mean I don't use `GET` at the 3rd step of my flow. Instead of `GET`, I utilize `Session` variables.) So still do I need to use `urlencode()` somewhere on `Session` variables? (Note: Even if you yes, I don't know HOW, that's another topic for me to study, for the time being *I only want to learn yes or no and why* cause I couldn't find the answer of this question in my research. of course if you define HOW part also, it will be really appreciated)
thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: @MikeB I read it. Thank you. For my question 1, I concluded that I don't need a replacement; `htmlspecialchars` is okey.

Answer (score 2):

Focus on why you have to do these two point not how. The how should allways just be a tip on how you "could possibly" fullfill the requirements. But if you just use what other tell you, you are at risk of not fully understanding the reasons and therefore unknowingly reintroduce a security risk.

4) This recommendation tries to avoid users "breaking out" of your input/textarea fields. Check for yourself, how this can be done in your form and act against that. Typically, a text input can be broken out of with the correct quote:

$value = '\'/>alert("hello");';
echo '

So in this case filtering the double quote would be enough (correct me if Im wrong). But filtering EVERYTHING you wont need is allways better. Prefer whitelisting against blacklisting filters.

5) This tries to avoid your URL from getting malformed. Can't give you a nice attack sample for now, but even a just malformed urls will probably make your app unusable.

BTW, typical PHP session IDs are plaintext only and URL safe. It would be even better to store them in a cookie with "http only" setting. You should not need naything besides that session id for normal session handling.

So, yes. Use these tips you mentioned, but understand the attack it aims to prevent and not just use them because polep tell you too.