# for xss attack prevention do i use prepared statement or callable statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

String getDBUSERByUserIdSql = "{call getDBUSERByUserId(?,?,?,?)}";

```
    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERByUserIdSql);

        callableStatement.setInt(1, 10);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);

        // execute getDBUSERByUserId store procedure
        callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

or

prepared statements

Comment: XSS is not related to SQL Injection; it requires a totally different approach which isn't provided by a database or its driver.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use [preparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), although this is for SQLi prevention rather than XSS

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand differences between  preparedStatement and callableStatement ,

**PreparedStatement**   *Use when you plan to use the SQL statements many times. The PreparedStatement interface accepts input parameters at runtime.*

**CallableStatement**   *Use when you want to access database stored procedures. The CallableStatement interface can also accept runtime input parameters.*

And to avoid `**XSS**` you could prefer **preparedStatement** as David said . refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: And still XSS is the wrong term - cross site scritping is usually referring to attacks in the browser. What you like to prevent is SQL-Injection - and this is completely 100% safely avoided by using Bind-Variables!