# PHP Security: XSS & SQL Injection

Tags: php, security, xss, sql-injection

I wanted to know what is the best way to prevent SQL Injection & XSS in PHP.

To prevent **SQL Injection**, we can escape the user input using **mysql_real_escape_string()** along with **strip_tags()**. Can we do anything else to make it more secure.

And, to prevent XSS, we can use **strip_tags()** along with strong data validation at server side.

Also, while sending the output to browser, we can use **htmlspecialchars()** to prevent the browser from applying any unintended meaning to any special sequence of characters that may be found.

Anybody can tell me, what else can be done to prevent the same?

Comment: [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](http://stackoverflow.com/q/71328/476)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)