# User submitted content in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have my website project where users can comment on posts. I want to allow users to submit YouTube videos for example. I want to display them in an iframe so others see a nice window of the video.

But that means that users can exploit the website using all the HTML tags and scripts?

put something like that 
`< a href="">< script>alert();< /script>">` 
which would break the site...

What ways do I have around that?

I want to make sure the user cannot use any tags.. but when link is posted it wraps it in the iframe.

One way I thought of is just to put separate input window only for urls which will be wrapped in iframe. but that complicates everything. I would also like to stick with one comment window.

## Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: You're asking how to prevent XSS. For that, you need to sanitize the input on the server. The above link shows how to do that in PHP, and [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site) discusses some of the best practices in general.

Comment: Don't let them provided HTML. Simply parse their text for a YouTube URL. Then perform a replace which inserts the `iframe` and uses the provided URL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't let users enter HTML.
2. Parse user comment for YouTube URL.
3. Replace URL with `<iframe>` pointing to provided URL.

Here is a super simple JavaScript example to work from.

https://jsfiddle.net/ntgs3ypt/

```js
var comment = document.querySelector('textarea');
var output = document.querySelector('div');

var str = comment.value;
var regex = /(https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/\w*)/;

if (regex.test(str)) {

  str = str.replace(regex, '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  output.innerHTML = str;

}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="comment">Lorem ipsum dolor https://www.youtube.com/embed/mr7FXvTSYpA lorem ipsum dolor</textarea>

<div class="output"></div>
```